# Receive data using ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, raspberrypi

I have connected ESP8266 to my Raspberry Pi's WiFi network and assigned a static IP.

My Arduino code

```cpp
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

String ssid = "Rpi";
String password = "raspberry";

SoftwareSerial esp(3, 2);// RX, TX

String server = "192.168.50.1"; //my Host


void setup() {
  esp.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  connectWifi();
  httpget();
  delay(1000);
}

void connectWifi() {
  String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"" + ssid + "\",\"" + password + "\"";
  esp.println(cmd);
  delay(4000);
  if (esp.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("Connected!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Cannot connect to wifi ! Connecting again...");
  }
  connectWifi();
}

/////////////////////////////GET METHOD///////////////////////////////
void httpget() {
  esp.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",1234");//start a TCP connection.
  if ( esp.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("TCP connection ready");
  }
  delay(1000);
  /*
    String getRequest =
    "GET " + uri + " HTTP/1.0\r\n" +
    "Host: " + server + "\r\n" +
    "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
    "\r\n";
  */
  String sendCmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  esp.print(sendCmd);
  //esp.println(getRequest.length() );
  delay(500);
  if (esp.find(">")) {
    Serial.println("Sending..");
    //  esp.print(getRequest);
    if ( esp.find("SEND OK")) {
      Serial.println("Packet sent");
      while (esp.available()) {
        String response = esp.readString();
      }
      esp.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  httpget();
}
```

I get this message

> > Cannot connect to wifi ! Connecting again...

In my Raspberry Pi I am constantly sending a signal to this IP address.

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.50.1' #Local Host
TCP_PORT = 1234            #Listening Port
BUFFER_SIZE = 12

SERVER_IP = '192.168.50.18'  #Arduino IP
SERVER_PORT = 3007            #Server Port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
#s.listen(1)

#(conn,addr) = s.accept()
#print 'Connection address: ',addr
while True:
    print 'Sending message'
    s.sendto('1',(SERVER_IP,SERVER_PORT))
    print 'Waiting for response'
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print 'received data: ',data
    print 'data recieved from: ',addr
    conn.close()
s.close()
```

But I can not see it in my Serial Monitor. Do I need to create a separate program for getting from WiFi?

Comment: you didn't start a server on esp8266 so nothing listens on esp for signals from raspberry

Comment: did you change the wifi mode in esp? it is in AP mode at default

Comment: softwareserial at 115200 has errors

Answer (score 1):

You are recursively calling `connectWifi()` and therefore your setup function results in an infinite loop.
You must not implement loops and for processes, which take some time, you should set and ask a flag.
Btw. why don't you use the official ESP WiFi library?

Comment: What is official ESP WiFi library?